# Aurelia - Computed property is re-calculated even when nested computed property has not changed

Tags: aurelia

I have computed property A which is dependent on X (`@computedFrom('X')`) and computed property B which is dependent on A (`@computedFrom('A')`).

My question is:
if x changes, but the result of A does not should B be re-calculated? Is this by design?

Comment: I think this question belongs to github more than to SO, because it may be a bug..